# access named scope through chained try in my case

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on old Rails project.

One student can have many courses. Here is my `course` class (in database, there is `courses` table):

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   named_scope :active, :conditions => ‘status is not null’
end
```

I want to access the first active course from student. I try to be safe, so do it in following way:

```
student.try(:courses).try(:active).try(:first).try(:name)
```

But I got error:

```
`undefined method` active' for []:Array`
```

Why is that?

BTW, I can do `student.courses.active.first`

Comment: What is the result of `student.try(:courses).class` and `student.courses.class`?

Comment: Do you have `has_many :courses` in Student model?

Comment: Wow some rails 3 code. It has been a while. Please make sure that `student.courses` returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` as it does not appear to do so currently given the error.

Comment: Yo souldn't need those `try` calls, `student.courses` should return an ActiveRecord::Relationship even if the result set is empty, same form `active`, and `first` should return an object or nil. The only `try` you need is the last one since it can be nil, but the rest should never be nil if you configured your relationships right.